# Eclipse Code Format Behavior

Tags: eclipse, formatting

My apologies if I'm missing something obvious but there's something that really bugs me about the Eclipse code formatter.  I don't want it to make any lines of code longer, only shorter.  Is there a way to force the formatter to behavior this way?

Example 1:

```
if (somethingIsTrue() || somethingElseIsTrue()) {
  //-- Do Something.
}
```

Example 2:

```
if (somethingIsTrue() ||
    somethingElseIsTrue()) {
  //-- Do something.
}
```

I don't want the formatter to touch either of these code blocks.  Currently it will always expand the second example to match the first.  I don't want that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

If this is Java, under `Preferences.Java.Code Style.Formatter` and then in tab  `Line Wrapping` there is a check box called `Never join lines`. That's worth a try...

Comment: It's new in Eclipse 3.5, and requires you also fine tune exactly when you break lines.

Comment: I was hoping for something a little less tedious.  Also, we're still stuck with 3.3 where I work.  So unfortunately this won't work for me.  Good to know there's at least an option when we upgrade though.